# The arc of the parabola $y=4^2, 0 \leq  \leq 2$ revolves around the $y$-axis. Find the volume of this parabolic cup.

Tags: calculus, integration

Any ideas? Cheers.

This is what I've got:
Integrate the cross section of the cup in the form
$ = \int^{16}_{0} (y)dy$.

Comment: Please check whether I have typed what you intended to write.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, have you found $A(y)$?

Comment: probably you learned a formula for the Volume or look it up in wiki

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. The cross section is a disk (since you have revolution) in the $xz$ plane. The radius of the disk is equal to $x$ when $z=0$ $$r=\sqrt{\frac y4}$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Take a disk element of radius $x$. The volume of this disk is $\pi x^2\mathrm dy$. Also from $y=4x^2$, $\mathrm dy=8x\mathrm dx$. So the total volume is $\int_{0}^{2}\pi x^2(8x\mathrm dx)=32\pi$ cubic units.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^22\pi x4x^2\operatorname dx=2\pi [x^4]_0^2=32\pi$.  Here I have used cylindrical shells.